# PIR with Arduino - detects only first motion

Tags: arduino-uno, sensors

The following is an Arduino sketch for 3 PIR sensors. Two PIRs can activate 1 buzzer and show status in an LCD. The third PIR activates a relay.

The problem is only the first motion gets detected and the "L" indicator stays on. After that there is no activity.

The same Arduino Uno board is working fine with other sketches. PIR sensors are also working. The sketch seems to be working on simulation as well.

[Link to simulation](https://circuits.io/circuits/5153140-the-unnamed-circuit)

"L" LED is the LED close to the 13th pin. above the TX,RX LEDs. The PIRs are set for the lowest time, sensitivity medium. The issue exists even without connecting the PIRs/relay. There is one beep from the buzzer, it happens 4-5 seconds after turning the board on, with that the "L" led goes on - forever.

The LCD also has an issue, it shows filled blocks on the first row, nothing else.

I tried connecting only one PIR and 1 buzzer to the board.

What is wrong?

```
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>

unsigned long time;
LiquidCrystal lcd(2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7);
int pir1Pin =9;
int pir2Pin =10;
int pir3Pin =11;
int buzzerPin =8;
int relayPin = 12;
int backlightPin = 13;
long previousMillis = 0;  
long interval = 1000;  

void setup() {
  lcd.begin(16, 2);
  pinMode(pir1Pin, INPUT);
  pinMode(pir2Pin, INPUT);
  pinMode(pir3Pin, INPUT);
  pinMode(relayPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(buzzerPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(backlightPin, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(relayPin,HIGH);
  delay(1000);
  digitalWrite(relayPin,LOW);
  Serial.begin(9600); 
}

void loop() {
  if(digitalRead(pir1Pin)== HIGH) {
    digitalWrite(backlightPin,HIGH);
    lcd.setCursor(0, 0);  
    lcd.print("Pir 1 Active");
    beep();
  } else {
    lcd.setCursor(0, 0);  
    lcd.print("Pir 1 is off");
    digitalWrite(backlightPin,LOW);
  }
   if(digitalRead(pir2Pin)== HIGH) {
     digitalWrite(backlightPin,HIGH);
     lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
     lcd.print("Pir 2 Active ");
     beep();
   } else {
     lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
     lcd.print("Pir 2 is off");
     digitalWrite(backlightPin,LOW);
  }
  if(digitalRead(pir3Pin)== HIGH) {
     while(digitalRead(pir3Pin)==HIGH) {
       digitalWrite(relayPin,HIGH);
     }
   } else {
     digitalWrite(relayPin,LOW);
   }
 }

void beep() {
  unsigned long currentMillis = millis();
  if(currentMillis - previousMillis > interval) {
    previousMillis = currentMillis;
    for (int i=0; i<500; i++) {
      digitalWrite(buzzerPin, HIGH);
      delayMicroseconds(500);
      digitalWrite(buzzerPin, LOW);
      delayMicroseconds(500);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You say “the "L" indicator stays on”.  What is the "L" indicator?  Also, what amount of time are the on-time pots on the PIR units set for?  If set for several seconds, could be causing the problem.

Comment: @ James Waldby - jwpat7, It is an LED marked as "L" on the board. the LED close to the 13th pin. above the TX,RX LEDs.
The PIRs are set for the lowest time, sensitivity medium.
The issue exists even without connecting the PIRs/relay.
There is one beep from the buzzer, it happens 4-5 seconds after turning the board on, with that the "L" led goes on - forever.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that all the PIR sensors and the LCD display are effectively powered.
this might fix your problem.

i'm saying this because the same thing seems to work in the simulation. Powering 3 PIR sensors and a LCD display with a USB is not a good idea.

Comment: But the same with only 1 PIR and 1 buzzer doesnt work ? withour LCD/additional PIRs

Comment: Are you 100% sure that the pinouts of the PIR sensors are correct and all of them work?

Comment: YES, I have tried reconnecting like 2-0 times in last 3-4 days. Also tested with higher voltage. Other PIR sketches are working.

Comment: @ShijilT  this seems odd. Try these, these might work. Place the Serial.begin(9600); line before any digital writes. Don't put the digital reads inside the if statements put them all in one place and store the results in variables.           res = digitalRead(pin); and then check them

Answer (score 1):

I don't really know what the problem is with your setup, but here are a few suggestions to try:

1. Several PIR guides ([1](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/pir-motion-sensor-hookup-guide),[2](http://bildr.org/2011/06/pir_arduino/),[3](https://learn.adafruit.com/pir-passive-infrared-proximity-motion-sensor),[4](https://www.wired.com/2012/09/using-motion-detectors-with-an-arduino/)) recommend using a pullup resistor on the open-collector signal pin of some models of PIR sensors.  You could also (or instead) say `pinMode(pir1Pin, INPUT_PULLUP);` (and so forth) rather than `pinMode(pir1Pin, INPUT);`.  Note, for each PIR, attach a voltmeter to its output (or, to its input on the Uno).  Trigger the PIR and verify that the signal acts as you expect it to.
2. Use a different pin number than 13 for your `backlightPin`.  The Uno's digital pin 13 corresponds to the on-board LED (presumably the LED your question calls 'L').  If you use separate pins for the backlight and the on-board LED, you can then use the on-board LED as a debugging aid.
3. Your code arrangement `if(digitalRead(pir1Pin)== HIGH){ ...` 
   `lcd.print(...); ... beep(); }else { ...`
   `lcd.print(...); ... }` (and similarly for `pir2Pin`) will print stuff to the LCD on every pass through `loop()`, that is, every few milliseconds.  It might make sense to have variables that record previous readings on those pins, and only update the LCD when a pin reading changes.  (Without other changes, this change would lead to only one beep when the PIR triggers, rather than a train of beeps at one-second intervals.  In this case if you want a train of beeps, you would need a beep-status variable.)

Answer (score 0):

To supplement, use an I2C backpack for the LCD and fmalpartida's newLiquidCrystal library. Set the jumper to autoreset the trigger.

Wire VCC to 5V

Wire S+ (outputs 3V3 when tripped) to D2 (INT0) - or whatever you use...

Wire GND to GND

Answer (score 0):

This is not a complete answer because I couldn't figure out why the beep only happens once. But if I'm not mistaken, if your code would work as you intend the first motion gets detected and the code jumps to beep. There it will be stuck for 500x(500+500) ms. You would never get results for pir2 or pir3 if the setup is in a way that you can't trigger pir2 independently from the others.

Therefore:

Use pulldown resistors as mentioned by others.

Read all the pir states and save them, and afterwards run the LCD code and then the beep code.

Your system will be unresponsive for as long as the beep code runs.